# Traversing a BST that holds two types of values

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, inorder

For an assignment, I am building a program that loads the words of a text document into a BST as well as the lines that they occur on in the document, so the nodes have two data members: a string (the word), and a Queue of integers (each line the word occurs on, with duplicates). The BST class is also a template class. For one of the parts of the assignment, I have to find the word with the maximum number of occurrences and print it out. However, the tree is sorted by the first data member (the strings), so I know finding the Queue with the greatest length means traversing the whole tree. The private traversal function definition that was included with the incomplete had this signature:

```
BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::Inorder(void visit(ItemType&, OtherType&), BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>* node_ptr) const
```

So, I made the functions like this:

```
public:
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::InorderTraverse(void visit(ItemType&, OtherType&)) const
{
   Inorder(visit, root_);
}  // end inorderTraverse

private:
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::Inorder(void visit(ItemType&, OtherType&), BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>* node_ptr) const
{
   if (node_ptr != nullptr)
   {
      Inorder(visit, node_ptr->GetLeftPtr());
      ItemType item = node_ptr->GetItem();
      OtherType other = node_ptr->GetOther();
      visit(item, other);
      Inorder(visit, node_ptr->GetRightPtr());
   }  
}
```

So it is passed a client function that can do some operation on the data members each node. However, I cannot figure out a way to make some function that *compares* the data members at each node. I tried adding two data members to hold the relevant information, and using a member function in the BST class and passing it to the Inorder function, but that giving me an error saying I am passing an "unresolved overloaded function type." For reference, here is what that looks like:

```
public:
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
bool BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::GetMaxOther(ItemType& theItem, OtherType& theOther)
{
    if(root_ == nullptr)
        return false; 

    InorderTraverse(MaxOtherHelper);
    theItem = maxOtherItem;
    theOther = maxOther;

    return true;
}

private:
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::MaxOtherHelper(ItemType& theItem, OtherType& theOther)
{
    if(theOther.Length() > maxOther.Length())
    {
        maxOther = theOther;
        maxOtherItem = theItem;
    }
}
```

It is clearly a sloppy solution, and it isn't working anyway. My question is, is there a way of doing this task without creating an entirely new, non-recursive inorder traversal function? The assignment came with the prototype for the traversal function, so I am trying to find if there is a way to do it with the function as provided.

tl;dr A BST holds two types of data members, is only sorted by one of them, how do I search using the other ones?

Comment: I don't think you can solve this without resorting to global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what purpose your BST is solving. BST stores data as a key value pair where the tree is sorted by the keys. If you need to search for a value, you have to traverse the tree or make a new tree which contains some information about the value so that you can use BST structure to get the required information quickly.

Another solution could be - keep track of the node which has the occurrence(count of the word) maximum, while adding new node or updating an existing node, if you find that value of this node exceeds the value of previous max, then you just need to change the tracking object/pointer.

If your requirement is only to get the word with maximum occurrence then you can use **Trie** which will be more efficient than BST for this purpose.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

### A more helpful InorderTraverse signature

The reason you have a compile error with `MaxOtherHelper` is that it has type 
`void(BinarySearchTree<I, O>::*)(I&, O&)` and not `void(I&, O&)`. If we implement `InorderTraverse` as the following

```
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::InorderTraverse(std::function<void(ItemType&, OtherType&)> visit, BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>* node_ptr) const
{
   if (node_ptr != nullptr)
   {
      Inorder(visit, node_ptr->GetLeftPtr());
      ItemType item = node_ptr->GetItem();
      OtherType other = node_ptr->GetOther();
      visit(item, other);
      Inorder(visit, node_ptr->GetRightPtr());
   }  
}
```

This allows us more flexibility on what `visit` can be, specifically, we can `std::bind` or use a lambda to pass member functions and still access `this`, e.g. `InorderTraverse([this](ItemType & item, OtherType & other){MaxOtherHelper(item, other);});`